# Traversing through them DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, traversal

Im having trouble trying to do the following:
When I hit the button(the first time), I want it to select the first box and then change the background to grey, and as the button is being pressed, I want it to jump to the next box and change that box into grey. Help Please!

---

```js
    const boxes = document.querySelector('#boxes');
    const button = document.querySelector('button');

    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let firstChild = boxes.firstElementChild;
        for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            firstChild.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
        }
    })
```

```css
    body {
        background: rgb(78, 78, 78);
    }

    .boxes {
        height: 600px;
        width: 380px;
        background: rgb(236, 236, 236);
        border-radius: 20px;
    }

    .box {
        height: 100px;
        background: rgb(26, 149, 187);
    }
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- My CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container boxes mt-5">
            <h1 class="text-center mb-4">App.js</h1>
            <div id='boxes' class="row justify-content-around">
                <div class="col-3 box "></div>
                <div class="col-3 box "></div>
                <div class="col-3 box "></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-4 justify-content-around">
                <div class="col-3 box "></div>
                <div class="col-3 box "></div>
                <div class="col-3 box "></div>
            </div>
            <div class="container text-center mt-4">
                <button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! It's very difficult to follow your question, you should edit it to better express your intent and how are you failing to achieve it.
However, I think you can achieve what I think you want by simply replacing `boxes.length` by `boxes.children.length` in your for loop and also changing `firstChild.nextElementSibling` for `boxes.children[i]`

Comment: I think you might want to iterate through the 'children' of  #boxes and not #boxes itself.

Comment: @subparry im so sorry. I have a hard time writing a good question lol. And thanx! That did change the background ... but I want the background to be gray on ONE box at a time. That changed all of them at the same time. I want to click my button, and turn on box to grey, then when I hit the button again, it'll jump to the next box, and change that one to grey

Comment: @fth Yes that worked thanx

Comment: @ObeJuarez You could do it by replacing the anonymous function in your event listener by a named function with a counter value as a closure, so every time you click on the button, the function updates another child.

Comment: @subparry Im fairly new at this, could you show me how that would be done? Id really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it using closures:

```js
const boxes = document.querySelector('#boxes');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

const createListener = () => {
  let counter = 0
  return () => {
    boxes.children[counter % 
boxes.children.length].style.backgroundColor = 'gray'
    counter++
  }
}

button.addEventListener('click', createListener())
```

I did not test it but it should work. If you don't understand what's going on please research on closures. It'll be very useful.

Comment: OH man that's great! Thanx for taking the time and showing me! Really appreciate it!

Comment: I’m glad it helped. If it satisfied your question, please mark the answer as accepted.